When is a vector parallel to a curve on $R^3$, with Riemannian connection?
Let $c: I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ be a differentiable curve, and $V$ a vector field tangent to $M$ along $c$.
Under what conditions is $V$ parallel?
My attempt:
Denote the standard basis by $x_i$ for $i \leq 3$. Express $V(p) = \sum_{i = 1}^3 v^i(p) \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$.
By definition,
$$
0 = \frac{DV}{dt} = \sum_{i = 1}^3 \frac{dv^i(p)}{dt} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} + v^i(p) \nabla_{\frac{dc}{dt}} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}
$$
However, I am confused on how to evaluate $\nabla_{\frac{dc}{dt}} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$: the way I understand
$$
\nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} = 0
$$
for all pairs $(i, j)$, since we are using the same coordinates $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$, so it should not change in any direction.
TLDR: If we take the connection the be the directional derivative (Levi-Civita), seems that Christoffel symbols should equal zero. But this implies that for any curve in R^3, a vector field is parallel iff it is constant, which doesn’t make any intuitive sense.
If anyone could point out the mistake, it would be appreciated :)

Let $c(t) = (c^1(t), c^2(t), c^3(t)).$ Then, $$\frac{dc}{dt}(t) = \sum_{j = 1}^3 \frac{dc^j}{dt}(t) \frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}.$$ Hence, using linerality of the Levi-Civita connection, we have $$\nabla_{\frac{dc}{dt}} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} = \sum_{j = 1}^3 \frac{dc^j}{dt} \nabla_{ \frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}}  \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} = 0.$$ Therefore, the vector field along $c$ is parallel if and only if $$\frac{dv^i}{dt} = 0,$$ that is, if and only if it is constant.

@RUBÉNIZQUIERDOLÓPEZ It is not true that $\nabla_{ \frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}}  \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} = 0.$ Instead: $$\nabla_{ \frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}}  \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} = \Gamma^k_{ji}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}.$$

Hmm what are the christoffel symbols on R^3? If we take the connection the be the directional derivative (Levi-Civita), does it not equal zero? But this implies that for any curve in R^3, a vector field is parallel iff it is constant, which doesn’t make any intuitive sense.

$\mathbb R^3$ as such does not have any Christoffel symbols. There are zillions of Levi-Civita connections on $\mathbb R^3$ that have non-zero Christoffel symbols. It sounds like you are working with the Euclidean metric and in Cartesian coordinates where the Christoffel symbols are all zero. Then $V$ is parallel along $c$ iff $$\nabla_{\dot c}V=\dot c^i\partial_iV^j\equiv 0,.$$ This does not mean that $V$ has to be constant. When the curve $c$ is for example the $x$-axis. Then $V$ is parallel along $c$ iff its components do not depend on $x,.$

Yes, you are right. What I meant is that $V$ needs to be constant along $c$. Thank you for the correction.
